# All WordPress multisite sites are using the primary site's URL for site assets

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I’ve got a multisite running on Roots Bedrock using subdomains. From a site user's point of view, the sites all appear to be working. Except, they are all using the primary site's URL for media assets, CSS and JS.

For example, the primary site URL is *abc.domain.com* and one sub-site URL is *xyz.abc.domain.com*. I have uploaded a media asset to the sub-site’s media library, but that asset’s URL, on the front end and in the Media Library in wp-admin, is https://abc.domain.com/app/uploads/sites/3/2021/05/image.jpg when it should be https://xyz.abc.domain.com/app/uploads/sites/3/2021/05/image.jpg

Additionally, inserting the theme CSS using the following:

```
wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $css, false, filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . $css), 'screen');
```

inserts the css with the path https://abc.domain.com/app/themes/theme-name/assets/css/main.min.css?ver=1620990609 across all sub-sites.

When on production, these sites are all going to be on separate domains, so I don't want any cross-domain errors. Can anybody help with this please?

**UPDATE**

Solution found https://github.com/roots/bedrock/issues/325